# Jenkinsfile define variable based on environment variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to set a boolean variable to true if one of my environment variables equals a string. I only want to run my test stage if this `RUN_TESTS` var is true.

```
pipeline{
  environment {
     RUN_TESTS = expression { "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}" == 'Test Pipeline' }
  }
 stages{
     stage('test'){
       when {
         expression { RUN_TESTS }
       }
       steps{
          // run my tests.......
     }
    
  }
}
```

The above is not working though.

How can I set a boolean variable based on the value of an environment variable that I can then use to conditionally run a pipeline stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you do not have to set environment variable in this case. You can evaluate expression directly in your stage:

```
pipeline{
 stages{
     stage('test'){
       when {
         expression { "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}" == 'Test Pipeline' }
       }
       steps{
          // run my tests.......
     }
    
  }
}
```

On the other hand if you still have to set the environment variable there are few ways to do it. Jenkins says:

```
Environment variable values must either be single quoted, double quoted, or function calls.
```

1. Wrap it in double quoted expression:

```
    environment {
        RUN_TESTS = "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME == 'Test Pipeline'}"
    }
```

2. Wrap this expression in the function call, something like this:

```
def run_tests() {
    return "${env.JOB_BASE_NAME}" == 'Test Pipeline' 
}

pipeline{
 environment {
    RUN_TESTS = run_tests()
 }
 stages{
     stage('test'){
       when {
         expression { RUN_TESTS }
       }
       steps{
          // run my tests.......
     }

  }
}
```

But in general I would go for first approach

Comment: I think the resulting RUN_TESTS value might be a string so you can't just do when { expression { RUN_TESTS} }   . Might need to do RUN_TESTS.toBoolean()

Comment: BTW, there is no need to quote the variable in expression. You can also omit `env.` if the variable always exists. So this works as well: `expression { JOB_BASE_NAME == 'Test Pipeline' }`